# Webservice and sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, wcf

I'm making a webservice that does some sql commands and outputs the results in JSON and it kinda works. But now I've been making some changes and I've ran into an issue I can't seem to fix.

The SQL command I want to run looks like this:

```
declare @param int
--set @param = 5

select u.SagsNr, uf.TekstWeb 
from UdlejningsSagFacilitet uf 
inner join UdlejningsSag u on uf.UdlejningsSagId = u.UdlejningsSagId 
where u.VisesPaaNettet = 1 and 
exists(select * from UdlejningsSagFacilitet uf inner join UdlejningsSag u on uf.UdlejningsSagId = u.UdlejningsSagId where TekstWeb like '%Oven%' and @param IS NULL OR u.SagsNr = @param) 
and @param IS NULL OR u.SagsNr = @param
```

Basically, when there is not given an ID I want to return everything. This works perfectly in SSMS. However! When I try to get this into my webservice it won't work. I think it should look like this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con = Database();

SqlDataAdapter daf = new SqlDataAdapter("select u.SagsNr, uf.TekstWeb " +
                                                    "from UdlejningsSagFacilitet uf " +
                                                    "inner join UdlejningsSag u on uf.UdlejningsSagId = u.UdlejningsSagId " +
                                                    "where u.VisesPaaNettet = 1 and exists(select * from UdlejningsSagFacilitet uf " +
                                                    "inner join UdlejningsSag u on uf.UdlejningsSagId = u.UdlejningsSagId " + 
                                                    "where TekstWeb like '%Oven%' and " + vSagsNr + " IS NULL OR u.SagsNr = " + vSagsNr + 
                                                    ") and " + vSagsNr + " IS NULL OR u.SagsNr = " + vSagsNr, con);

DataTable dtf = new DataTable();
daf.Fill(dtf);
string jsonf = GetJson(dtf);
return jsonf;
```

Here vSagsNr takes the place of @param.

If I provide a value for vSagsNr this works but if I don't I get an error:

```
  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.
  ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
  ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
  ved System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
  ved System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
  ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
  ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
  ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
  ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
  ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
  ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
  ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
  ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
  ved System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
  ved System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
  ved System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
  ved System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
  ved WCFTest3.Service1.POSTBoligSøgning(Nullable`1 vSagsNr, String vFacilitet) i C:\Users\chm\source\repos\WCFTest3\WCFTest3\Service1.svc.cs:linje 54
ClientConnectionId:5bc85eb2-3e2a-46ef-b941-4419eab09b43
Error Number:156,State:1,Class:15
```

Line 54 is the "daf.Fill(dtf);" part.
I'm thinking the SQL turns out wrong somehow but I can't seem to figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Error near the IS, eh? Not sure about your programming language, could it be vSagsNr needs to be converted to text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the query `"where TekstWeb like '%Oven%' and " + vSagsNr + " IS NULL` is going to fail if you don't give a value to `vSagsNr`. It would look like this: `"where TekstWeb like '%Oven%' and IS NULL`

As you can see, that query is incorrect. So your better option is to separate the query in multiple strings and each time you are going to put a condition regarding `vSagsNr` you check for its value and if its null or empty you remove that condition entirely from the query string.

```
if (vSagsNr != null && !vSagsNr.equals("")) {
    /* Add: "and " + vSagsNr + " IS NULL OR u.SagsNr = " + vSagsNr" to your query */
} else {
    /* Nothing, the query does not need that condition as the value is not specified */
}
```